# Как сделать запрос на скачивание файла

Tags: html, html5

Необходимо сделать запрос на скачивание аудио файла, сейчас мой код выглядит так:

```html
<a href="audio.mp3">download</a>
```

Comment: Во-первых, переведите вопрос на русский язык, а во-вторых, https://webref.ru/html/a/download

Comment: @andreymal, не нужно украинцам давать российские сайты, в большинстве случаев они будут заблокированными.

Comment: @OliverPatterson во-первых, нигде не сказано что тут украинцы, а во-вторых, это не мои проблемы

Comment: @andreymal, окей, тогда что делать, если вопрос так и останется закрытым и у него не будет ответа, а лишь ответ в комментариях, а ссылка уже устареет? Не ужели нельзя дать нормальный ответ, не ссылкой?

Comment: Предоставлять возможность скачивать МП3 на сайте могут только авторы произведений, в остальных случаях речь идёт о нарушении авторских прав. Любому известно, как авторы музыки относятся к скачиванию.

Comment: @Опан предоставлять возможность скачивать что угодно могут только его авторы, это не специфично для MP3

Answer (score 1):

У тега `<a>` есть атрибут `download`, он указывает, что вместо перехода к файлу, будет выполнена загрузка файла.

```html
<a href="audio.mp3" download>download</a>
```

Значением для атрибута `download` можно указать новое имя для файла, иначе будет использовано оригинальное.

```html
<a href="audio.mp3" download="new-name">download</a>
```